Pair of pants with k-genus
Let $\mathbb{H}$ be the hyperbolic plane. An usual($0$-genus) pair of pants $P_0$ is a $2$ dimensional sphere with $3$ holes and constant curvature $-1$. The boundary of a pair of pants consists of three closed geodesics. Analogously consider a pair of pants $P_k$ with $k$ genus i.e. a closed hyperbolic surface with $k$-genus, $3$ holes and constant curvature $-1$. The boundary of $P_k$ consists of $3$ closed geodesics. It is known that $P_k$ can be decomposed into 2k+1 usual($0$-genus) pair of pants $P_0$'s.
The hyperbolic hexagon $H_0$ is a building block for $P_0$. It can be constructed from two identical $H_0$'s by gluing them along three non-consecutive sides. On the other hand, $H_0$ can be recovered by cutting $P_0$ into two idential $H_0$'s. My goal is to find a building block corresponding to $P_k$ which can be embedded in $\mathbb{H}$ like $H_0$. For simplicity we take $k=1$. If we cut $P_1$ (as in $P_0$ case), we get a hexagonal hyperbolic surface with geodesic sides and a circular hole. We call this surface $H_1$. Since a circle is not a geodesic in $\mathbb{H}$, $H_1$ can not be "embedded" in $\mathbb{H}$.  Is there any way to obtain a polygonal building block with geodesic boundaries for $P_1$ which can be embedded in $\mathbb{H}$? One possiblity is to look at a cover of $P_1$ which is easy to decompose into simple building blocks.
Thank you!!

Your question is unclear. To begin with, what so you mean by a "pair of pants with k-genus?" Next, is it just a topological surface, or a hyperbolic surface with geodesic boundary, or something else? The rest is even less clear...

Thank you for the comment. I have edited the question. I hope it is understandable now.
